# How Might I organize vertex data in WebGL for a frame-by-frame (very specific) animated program?

Tags: graphics, webgl, shader, vertex-buffer

I have been working on an animated graphics project with very specific requirements, and after quite a bit of searching and test coding, I have figured that I could take several approaches, but the Khronos and MDN documentation I have been reading coupled with other posts I have seen here don't answer all of my questions regarding my particular project. In the meantime, I have written short test programs (setting infrastructure for testing).

Firstly, I should describe the project:

The main object drawn to the screen is a simple quad surrounded by a black outline (LINE_LOOP or LINES will do, probably, though I have had issues with z-fighting...that will be left for another question). When the user interacts with the program, exactly one new quad is created and immediately drawn, but for a set amount of time its vertices move around until the quad moves to its final destination. (Note that translations won't do.) Random black lines are also drawn, and sometimes those lines also move around.

Once one of the quads reaches its final spot, it never moves again.
A new quad is always atop old quads (closer to the screen). That means that I need to layer the quads and lines from oldest to newest.
*this also means that it would probably be best to assign z-values to each quad and line, even if the graphics are in pixel coordinates and use an orthographic matrix. Would everyone agree with this?

Given these parameters, I have a few options with varying levels of complexity:

1> Take the object-oriented approach and just assign a buffer to each quad, and the same goes for the random lines. --creation and destruction of buffers every frame for the one shape that is moving. I truthfully think that this is a terrible idea that might only work in a higher level library that does heavy optimization underneath. This approach also doesn't take advantage of the fact that almost every quad will stay the same.

```
[vertices0] ... , [verticesN]
Draw x N (many draws for many small-size buffers)
```

2> Assign a z-value to each quad, outline, and line (as mentioned above). Allocate a huge vertex buffer and element buffer to store all permanently-in-their-final-positions quads. Resize only in the very unlikely case someone interacts for long enough. Create a second tiny buffer to store the one temporary moving quad and use `bufferSubData` every frame. When the quad reaches its destination, `bufferSubData` it into the large buffer and overwrite the small buffer upon creation of the next quad...all on the same frame. The main questions I have here are: is it possible (safe?) to use `bufferSubData` and draw it on the same frame? Also, would I use `DYNAMIC_DRAW` on both buffers even though the larger one would see fewer updates?

```
[permanent vertices ... | uninitialized (keep a count)]
bufferSubData -> [tempVerticesForOneQuad]
Draw 2x
```

3> Still create the large and small buffers, but instead of using `bufferSubData` every frame, create a second shader program and add an attribute for the new/moving quad that explicitly sets the vertex positions for the animation (I would pass vertex index attributes). Only draw with the small buffer when the quad is moving. For the frame when the quad reaches its destination, draw both large and small buffer, but then `bufferSubData` the final coordinates into the large permanent buffer to be used in the *next* frame.

```
switchToShaderProgramA();
[permanent vertices...| uninitialized (keep a count)]
switchToShaderProgramB();
[temp vertices] <- shader B accepts indices for each vertex so we can do all animation in the vertex shader
---last frame of movement arrives : bufferSubData into the permanent vertices buffer for when the the next quad is created
```

I get the sense that the third option might be the best, but I would like to learn whether there are some other factors that I did not consider. For example, my assumption that a program switch, additional attributes, and vertex shader manipulation would be faster than just substituting the buffer values as in 2>. The advantage of approach 3> (I think) is that I can defer the buffer substitution to a time when nothing needs to be drawn.

Still, I am still not sure of how to work with the randomly-appearing lines. I can't take the "single quad vertex buffer" approach since the number of lines cannot be predicted. Might I also allocate a large buffer for the moving lines? Those also stay after the quad is finished moving, though I don't think that I could use the vertex shader trick because there would be too many attributes to set (as opposed to the 4 for the one quad). I suppose that I could create a large "permanent line data" buffer first, but what to do during the animation is tricky because the lines move. Maybe bufferSubData() + draw on the same frame is not terrible? Or it could be. This is where I need advise.

I understand that this question might not be too specific code-wise, but I don't believe that I would be allowed to show the core of the program. All I have is the typical WebGL boilerplate ready.

I am looking forward to hearing people's thoughts on how I might proceed and whether there are any trade-offs I might have missed when considering the three options above.
Thank you in advance, and please feel free to ask any additional questions if clarification is necessary.

Comment: How many quads and random lines are you likely to draw? That will help determine reasonable strategies.

Comment: @user1118321 The screen is 640 x 480, and each quad is a maximum of 50 x 50 I believe. I can take a closer look tomorrow, but the lines are greater in number. I * think* I could afford a large buffer allocation + keeping track of its size (there is no particular bound on the nber of quads, but in practice you might get beyond a few hundred if you're determined), but without specific experience, it is hard to say. The fragment shader is just a pass-through "output a single color" shader. I am curious whether option 2 or 3 is "better." The same goes for 1, which I still think would be wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, for what you're describing, it doesn't sound to me like it matters which you choose. On modern hardware, drawing a few hundred quads and a few thousand lines each frame would not really tax the hardware much.

Having said that, I agree that approach 1 seems very inefficient. Approach 2 sounds perfectly fine. You can safely draw a buffer on the same frame that you uploaded the data. I don't think it matters much whether you use `DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `STATIC_DRAW` for the buffer. I tend to think of dynamic buffers as being something you're updating every frame. If you only update it every few seconds or less, then static is fine. Approach 3 is also fine. Between 2 and 3, I'd say do whichever is easier for you to understand and program.

Likewise, for the lines, I would use a separate buffer. It sounds like that one changes per frame, so I would use `DYNAMIC_DRAW` for that. Allocating a single large buffer for it and performing a `glBufferSubData()` per frame is probably a fine strategy. As always, trying it and profiling it will tell you for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts. If I may ask a follow-up question---
One advantage of the "many tiny buffers" approach is that I could disable depth culling and just draw all quads and lines in order without worrying about z-fighting. However, because I agree that approaches 2 and 3 might be better efficiency-wise, I don't see any way to do conditional depth-testing (e.g. keep depth testing, but for each separate draw call, (first triangles, then lines), pick the later fragment if there is a conflict between triangle and line). The closest is: (see part 2)

Comment: `gl.enable(gl.POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL); gl.polygonOffset(1.0, 1.0);`, @user1118321 but I would still need to set the z-coordinate explicitly for each "plane" (quad + any lines on that quad). Also, isn't there a chance that I could force a quad beyond the far plane? I'm using an orthographic matrix set with -1000, 1000, but I suppose that the squash to -1. to 1. might cause floating point rounding errors that could break everything if I have too many quad layers (one per quad/its lines). Is this a valid concern? How else might I work around this? I think that polygonOffset is part of the solution.

Comment: It's a valid concern, but it's one of those things that I'd put in the "I'll worry about it when I run into it in practice" category. I've had some success using `gl.polygonOffset()` in the past. It's worth a look.

Comment: I see. I'll probably ask a separate question in reference to this one if there are more developments. Thank you again for your thoughts!